# What is this group isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Let $G=S_n$ act on $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and let $A\subset \{1,2,...,n\}$ so that $|A|=k$. If $G_A$ is the subset of $G$ that fixes all the points in $A$, what is $G_A$ isomorphic to?

It makes sense that $G_A$ would be isomorphic to $S_{n-k}$ since, the $k$ points are fixed and that would result in $k$ one-cycles. What would be the best way of going about proving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose, wlog, that $A=\{n-k+1,\cdots,n\}$.  Then, consider $G_A$ and $S_{n-k}$.  We can construct an explicit bijection between $G_A$ and $S_{n-k}$.

- If $\sigma\in S_{n-k}$, then $\widetilde{\sigma}\in G_A$ is defined as follows:
  $$
  \widetilde{\sigma}(i)=\begin{cases}\sigma(i)&i\leq n-k\\i&i>n-k\end{cases}.
  $$
- If $\widetilde{\sigma}\in G_A$, then define $\sigma\in S_{n-k}$ as follows:
  $$
  \sigma(i)=\widetilde{\sigma}(i).
  $$

This makes the composition in Matt Samuel's answer explicit (Matt Samuel's answer is better as it is more general, this just gives an explicit picture of what is happening).

Answer (score 11):

Take a bijection $f$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}-A$ with $\{1,2, \ldots ,n-k\}$. Then $\sigma\mapsto f\circ \sigma\circ f^{-1}$ gives you an isomorphism with $S_{n-k}$. (There are details to fill in here.)